# How on trigger onBlur before form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

I have some `input` box in which I am having `onBlur` function called for validation.

> The problem I am facing is that when I directly click on submit button without tabbing out from the `input` box, form is getting submitted before `onBlur` function call and the validation is not happening.

Can someone suggest a workaround here. I am using javascript and JQuery in my JSP page.

Comment: Do the validation on submit as well

Comment: there are lots of textboxes, so I'll prefer the onBlur call instead of validating those textboxes again.

Comment: You can make the new version (see below) more efficient by only blurring the current focused input in the submit handler, but it now works for `Enter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be simpler options, but you could stop the submit button and then submit the form on the next frame (using setTimeout):

e.g. something like

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    e.preventDefault():
    setTimeout(function(){ 
       $form.submit();
    }, 0);
});
```

The problem then is how to allow `Enter` key form submission to work, if you are on the field you want to validate when you press `Enter`. You should probably also validate the entire form on `submit` too.

I came up with the following, using the submit event instead (so `Enter` is handled) and toggling a class on the `form` (to avoid recursion), which should do what you want:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    $form.toggleClass('ignore');
    if ($form.hasClass('ignore')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $form.find('input[type=text]').blur();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $form.submit();
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7uLfra3b/2/

You can make the new version more efficient by only blurring the current focused input in the submit handler, but it now allows for `Enter`.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot, just need to figure out a way to bypass Enter key.

Comment: This thread is pretty old, but this is what I did to capture Enter key. For each input add an event listener for keyDown and if that key is Enter do the validation... . For me the input is a react component so basically I just add a keyDown event listener to the component and 'signal' the parent component to prevent form submission if there are any errors.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can disable the submit button when input is on focus, and enable it when input is on blur, something like this:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
  $('submit').attr("disabled", true);
}).blur(function(){
  $('submit').attr("disabled", false);
});
```

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Q: Will still actually stop the Enter key submitting the form?

Answer (score 1):

please see this example.

```js
    $('#blurtest').blur(function(){
        $('#bluredText').html($(this).val());
    });
    
    $('#testform').submit(function(e){
        $('#blurtest').trigger('blur');
        $(this).submit();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Blured Text: <span id="bluredText"></span>
<form name="testform" id="testform" action="" method="post">
    <label>Enter Text:</label> 
    <input name="blurtest" id="blurtest" value="" />
    <input name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" type="Submit"/>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/narayand4/xvf2x7ee/22/

i think you can solve your issue like this way.